# Routing Page from Sub-Folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms with master pages. I have the following routing rule in my Global.asax.cs file:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("", "Ministries", "~/Ministries/Ministries.aspx");
```

It works fine when I alter the rule above to display the content page from the root. When I navigate to the page using http://localhost/church/ministries the page displays the directory view. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the route a name and change your folder name since the route and folder names collide.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ministries", "Ministries", "~/Ministry/Ministries.aspx");
```

and you must navigate to it like this (from an asp:linkbutton example, use whatever)

```
NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:RouteName=ministries %>"
```

Just hardcoding the path does not send it through asp's routing engine, you were pointing it to the directory, it does not know any better.

Comment: ahh...folder name is the same as the route. Rename the folder and adjust the route, should work. Directory view will take precedence over the routing.

Comment: That did it. Just to clarify, I re-created the Web form just to be sure it was correct, and used the following rule: routes.MapPageRoute("Ministries", "Ministries", "~/Ministry/Ministries.aspx");